# can't collect a weapon in fallout shelter

Tags: fallout-shelter

I just crafted a weapon in Fallout Shelter, but it says I can't collect it because my inventory is full.  Just built a storage room, but still can't collect.  Any help?

Answer (score 2):

If you just built your first storage room, then perhaps you still don't have space.

You can open your storage from the Pip-Boy menu. It's the icon that looks like one box stacked on two others.

Once you open your storage, look at the "Storage Space" at the bottom. Mine says 90/145. This means I can hold 145 items, and I currently have 90, so I have room for 55 more. If the number on the left is not smaller than the one on the left, you'll need more space.

You can get more space by selling things in your inventory or building more storage. You can extend your storage room, build another storage room, or upgrade it.